# Typescript: Object(..) is not a function in decorators module

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am using decorators with `"experimentalDecorators": true` in a CRA. Imagine the following situation:

```
my-app/
└── ..
    ├── decorators.ts
    └── stuffBeingDecorated.ts
        ├── ClassFoo
        └── SpecialClass
```

In `decorators.ts` I have some functions that are imported and used to decorate classes and methods in `stuffBeingDecorated.ts`.

One of my decorators is applied to methods both in `ClassFoo` and `SpecialClass`. At runtime, I'd like to know if the method being decorated belongs to SpecialClass or not, and change its behavior.

I attempted this:

```js
// decorators.ts
import SpecialClass from 'stuffBeingDecorated';

export const myDeco = () => {
  return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const oldFunc = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (target instanceof SpecialClass) {
        // do something
      } else {
        // do something else
      }
      oldFunc.apply(this, args);
    };
  };
};
```

This is where my problems begin: I get error `Object(..) is not a function` by trying to use any imported class from `stuffBeingDecorated.ts`, including other classes that are not decorated themselves.

For example:

```js
// stuffBeingDecorated.ts
@decorated()
export class Foo {}

export class NotDecorated {}

// decorators.ts
import { NotDecorated } from 'stuffBeingDecorated'

const notDeco = new NotDecorated()
```

Gives me the same exact error. However, I can use those classes normally if I import them anywhere else. I assume this has to do with some kind of circular dependency between the module containing the decorated classes, and the decorator module itself, but I can't quite reach a conclusion.

So my questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I achieve what I wanted to do in the first place (aka, my first code example) ?